# How to search for documents whose specific field contains all items from one list and does not contain any item from another list?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to get documents whose specific field contains all items from one list and does not contain any item from another list.
For example:

The document may look something like this:

```
{
          "name" : "text",
          "number" : "1.0",
          "price" : "3.99"
}
```

I have a list of strings, which have to be in the field "name".

```
has_to_be = [element1, element2, ...]
```

And I have a list of strings which cannot be in the field "name".

```
cannot_be = [element1, element2, ...]
```

I want to get the documents, whose field "name" consists all strings from has_to_be and does not consist any word from cannot_be.

I tried something like this:

```
"query": 
{"bool": 
{"must": [
{"match": {"name": "element1"}}, 
{"match": {"name": "element2"}}
]}}
```

But I didn't get any hits.

I tried also this query:

```
GET /index_name/_search?q=name:+element1 +element2
```

(Additional question: How can I send such a query from python to elasticsearch?)

But I get also hits, which didn't contain all the elements (element1 or element2).

Comment: It may help to post your code, and a working test case that doesn't get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

About your filter needs, you can do what you need with a boolean query and specify the matching operator.

I used some test documents:

```
POST test/_doc
{
  "elt": ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "elt": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "elt": ["test1", "test2"]
}
```

And below and example query where document must contains `test1 AND test2 AND test3 but NOT test 4`.
So the first document will be the only one to match.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "elt": {
              "query": "test1 test2 test3",
              "operator": "AND"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
           "elt": {
              "query": "test4 test5",
              "operator": "OR"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```